# Getting bootstrap glyphicons to work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have included `bootstrap.css` into my html document. Now I have been trying to display `glyphicons` but they simply do not show up. Can anyone help?

I'v tried

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i>
```

and this

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify">&#xe055;</i>
```

also tried

Nothing shows up on the page

Comment: Do you also have the glyphicons font in the `../fonts/` directory?

Comment: please, provide your html page.

Comment: When I downloaded bootstrap, font directory was not there

Answer (score 0):

- make sure you have also downloaded the fonts folder..
- in your bootstraps.css search for this class

  @font-face {
      font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  ```
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-
  opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') 
  format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') 
  format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') 
  format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-
  regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
  ```

  }
- make sure the route of the file is correct other wise you can change it.

Comment: aparently fonts folder no longer exists in Bootstrap v4. Glyphicons have been dropped